# Pyinstaller gives " 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH" when the .exe is ran, but the actual python script works fine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exe, pyinstaller

So I have a python script that uses selenium and everything works perfectly fine when I run it, but I wanted to turn it into a .exe file so I used pyinstaller. I made the spec files n stuff but when I actually run the .exe I get `chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH` when normally I dont get that when I run the python script

here is a code snippet of my actual python script where I set the path.

```
path = os.getcwd()        
    if (browser == 'c'):
        driver_path = path + '//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe'
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
        if (hidden == 'T'): options.add_argument('headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
    if (browser == 'f'):
        driver_path = path + '//geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64//geckodriver.exe'
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
        if (hidden == 'T'): options.add_argument('headless')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
```

If you need any more code just let me know.

Comment: This code uses `os.getcwd()`, hence ensure that your `.exe` file resides in the same path as `os.getcwd()`, any other path would not let your code work as the `chromedriver.exe` path turns out to be incorrect.

Comment: Try the code by hardcoding the driver_path to the absolute path of the `chromedriver`. Best solution here would be to have this absolute path stored as an environment variable and then used in the code.

Comment: Is the installer run as a different user? Is so the other user will have a different PATH, and the ChromeDriver might not be in that user's path, but it is for you.

Comment: @GregBurghardt No it isn't instlled as a different user, I dont think thats the problem.

Comment: @CavinDsouza My main goal is to try and not hard code the absolute path so I can share it with others

Comment: @CavinDsouza the thing w `os.getcwd()` its that `//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe'` is always going to be in the same directory so I dont think that is the problem either

Comment: @CavinDsouza nvm you were right. Im a moron and forgot to actually add the directory lmao. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory with chromepath wasn't in the correct place. Make sure to double check your directory hierarchy.